# How can I have $http return mock data while a service endpoint is not ready?

Tags: angularjs

In an Angular service (provider.service) that uses $http, is there a way to periodically turn on and off what certain calls using $http will return?

Here's my scenario: we are using $http to consume web services built by another development team. When those services are not yet ready (or break) we don't want development efforts to halt on our end. We simply need to temporarily turn off that specific call and have it return mocked data.

I've seen $httpBackend being used to mock out HTTP calls, but I'm not sure that will work for me, and if it would, I'm not sure how this would look or be configured.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making your $http calls from a data service, you can set toggles in your service.  Don't even make the http call if you know it will fail. Alternatively you could probably even make a whole mock data service to use at dev time, and replace it with the actual service when your backend is ready, avoiding issues of dev code being there in production. This is one of the reasons people say you should never reference $http in controllers.

See the [AngularJS Style Guide - Data Services](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#data-services) for a better explanation than I could ever write.

Comment: Our services that use $http contain a lot of processing business logic, and just use $http to persist and/or get information. So we wouldn't want to swap out a mock version of the entire service, just of $http. I suppose your suggestion would work in that instead of injecting $http into the service, inject a wrapper around $http. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: Yes.  That would work nicely as a quick fix. I would try to keep this simple, as it is just a development-time workaround. If you go crazy and start injecting $http interceptors and things of that nature, you may have some unexpected results when you start actually talking to the endpoints again.

Comment: If this is a commonplace issue in your company/team, you might consider having a dedicated layer for business logic between the presentation and persistence layers.

Comment: Let me try this for a bit and see how things go. It is likely I will accept your answer. Thanks!